# How can I get NLP Recommender function to work?

Tags: nlp, recommendation-engine

I am struggling to get my recommender function working.

Speech is a dataframe and "Name" is a column containing the names of presidents. The cosine_sim is a cosine similarity matrix that performs ok.

I get a very simple but frustrating error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-227-2f900b10c771> in <module>
     17 
     18 # Generate recommendations
---> 19 print(get_recommendations("John Adams", cosine_sim, indices))

<ipython-input-227-2f900b10c771> in get_recommendations(name, cosine_sim, indices)
      4 def get_recommendations(name, cosine_sim, indices):
      5     # Get index of movie that matches title
----> 6     idx = indices[Name]
      7     # Sort the movies based on the similarity scores
      8     sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))
```

Who can point out my mistake?

```
NameError: name 'Name' is not defined



# Generate mapping between name and index
indices = pd.Series(speech.index, index=speech['Name']).drop_duplicates()

def get_recommendations(name, cosine_sim, indices):
    # Get index of speeches that matches title
    idx = indices[Name]
    # Sort the names based on the similarity scores
    sim_scores = list(enumerate(cosine_sim[idx]))
    sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    # Get the scores for 10 most similar speeches
    sim_scores = sim_scores[1:11]
    # Get the name indices
    speech_indices = [i[0] for i in sim_scores]
    # Return the top 10 most similar speeches
    return speech['Name'].iloc[speech_indices]


# Generate recommendations 
print(get_recommendations("John Adams", cosine_sim, indices))
```

Comment: `Name` vs `name` ?

Comment: No, I wish it was that simple :(

Comment: NameError is about an undefined variable name. `name` is defined as argument of the function but you have used `Name` later as an index for `indices`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I used code from Datacamp. For some reason the code worked fine for them.